# How to get variable in query string without using "?"

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to use GET to capture member IDs in a URL without using the ?name=variable. For instance, instead of using mydomain.com/folder?id=1234 I would like to use mydomain.com/folder/1234 and pick up the id "1234" in the code so I can pass it to another URL.

This page simply redirects by using: `<iframe src="http://redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php" />`

I have no control over the server I'm redirecting to, but need the variable passed to it. I can append the redirect URL with `?id=1234` ie `<iframe src="http://redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php?id=1234" />`

Their code will pick up the id by using `<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a rewrite rule.  You can use rewrite rules in conjunction with a redirect or proxy.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO This question is very specific, and he can't have code to do anything with it if he doesn't know at all how to begin.

Comment: @Brad Then OP is lacking a basic understanding of the problem being solved; which is off-topic.

Comment: I think you are asking for the rewrite that would take as its input `mydomain.com/folder/1234`, and redirects it to `mydomain.com/folder?id=1234` - did I understand correctly?

Comment: I'll try it Floris. It may be the solution. I MODIFIED my original post to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use .htaccess for this.  Create a file called `.htaccess` and put it in the same folder mydomain.com is referencing.  Put something like the following in there

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder?id=$1 [L]
```

Note: mod_rewrite must be enabled on apache, but it usually is.

**Update:** I've updated the .htaccess to reflect a local URL since you've made your desired functionality more clear.  Using this .htaccess in conjunction with `<iframe src="http://redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" />` should do the trick.

Comment: I think there's one too many `folder/` in your string... but otherwise this looks a lot like the answer I was about to write. Thanks for saving me the trouble.

Comment: I included 2x /folder because that's what OP mentioned.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php?id=$1 [L]` should be the correct formulation based on the updated question.

Comment: Well, the question changed, so now .htaccess is not the solution

Comment: I disagree that `.htaccess` is not the solution; apparently I am reading the question differently.  My vote stands...

Comment: I placed the .htaccess file in mydomain.com/folder, after changing URL and "folder"s in the file to the name of the specific URL and folders I'm using, and it didn't work

Comment: @Floris .htaccess is still needed, just not in how it was being done... I've updated my post.

Comment: @Webnet I updated the two files to reflect your modified answer. However, when I enter the url `http://mydomain.com/folder/1234` I just get a 404

Comment: @user1322707 - turn on logging of the Apache server to tell you exactly what the rewrite engine is doing; see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel . Once you know what your rule is doing (vs what you thought it's doing) it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and use something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to write my own answer down. The following two lines in your `.htaccess` should do exactly what you are asking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

According to the rewrite rule test site http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ , when I use an input of `folder/1234`, it is redirected to `redirect_domain.com/folder/index.php?id=1234` which is exactly what you asked for. There is no need for the `<iframe`... or any actual files in the `/folder/` other than the `.htaccess` ...